! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup - LATEX
I met these latex format problem, anyone can offer some help?
the .tex file:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[bf,singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setmainfont[UprightFeatures={SmallCapsFont=AlegreyaSC-Regular}]{Alegreya}

\usepackage{framed,color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{248,248,248}

\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.05}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.8}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.8}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75}

\renewenvironment{quote}{\begin{VF}}{\end{VF}}
\let\oldhref\href
\renewcommand{\href}[2]{#2\footnote{\url{#1}}}

\ifxetex
  \usepackage{letltxmacro}
  \setlength{\XeTeXLinkMargin}{1pt}
  \LetLtxMacro\SavedIncludeGraphics\includegraphics
  \def\includegraphics#1#{% #1 catches optional stuff (star/opt. arg.)
    \IncludeGraphicsAux{#1}%
  }%
  \newcommand*{\IncludeGraphicsAux}[2]{%
    \XeTeXLinkBox{%
      \SavedIncludeGraphics#1{#2}%
    }%
  }%
\fi

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{kframe}{%
\medskip{}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{.8em}
 \def\at@end@of@kframe{}%
 \ifinner\ifhmode%
  \def\at@end@of@kframe{\end{minipage}}%
  \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}%
 \fi\fi%
 \def\FrameCommand##1{\hskip\@totalleftmargin \hskip-\fboxsep
 \colorbox{shadecolor}{##1}\hskip-\fboxsep
     % There is no \\@totalrightmargin, so:
     \hskip-\linewidth \hskip-\@totalleftmargin \hskip\columnwidth}%
 \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-\width
   \@totalleftmargin\z@ \linewidth\hsize
   \@setminipage}}%
 {\par\unskip\endMakeFramed%
 \at@end@of@kframe}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{Shaded}{
}{\renewenvironment{Shaded}{\begin{kframe}}{\end{kframe}}}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{rmdblock}[1]
  {
  \begin{itemize}
  \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{
    \raisebox{-.7\height}[0pt][0pt]{
      {\setkeys{Gin}{width=3em,keepaspectratio}\includegraphics{images/#1}}
    }
  }
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{1em}
  \begin{kframe}
  \item
  }
  {
  \end{kframe}
  \end{itemize}
  }
\newenvironment{rmdnote}
  {\begin{rmdblock}{note}}
  {\end{rmdblock}}
\newenvironment{rmdcaution}
  {\begin{rmdblock}{caution}}
  {\end{rmdblock}}
\newenvironment{rmdimportant}
  {\begin{rmdblock}{important}}
  {\end{rmdblock}}
\newenvironment{rmdtip}
  {\begin{rmdblock}{tip}}
  {\end{rmdblock}}
\newenvironment{rmdwarning}
  {\begin{rmdblock}{warning}}
  {\end{rmdblock}}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\urlstyle{tt}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
  \thm@preskip=8pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
  \thm@postskip=\thm@preskip
}
\makeatother

\frontmatter


and the error message:
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\endMakeFramed ...eight \z@ \penalty -100 \egroup 
                                                  \begingroup \fb@put@frame ...
l.907   \end{rmdtip}

I feel that the error is in rmdtip, although I tried everything possible, I can not generate the pdf file. I have already updated TinyTex, but nothing.
Anyone can offer help?
Really appreciate all the comments!

Please add a [mre], not just a code fragment which lacks a class etc.
